# Can my Android app know and detect which carrier the phone operates under at any given moment?

Tags: android, carrier

Is there an an Android API that enables my App to detect and know the Carrier of the the phone? I will be glad to get the code...? Thanx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [TelephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName%28%29)

Comment: This method is not always reliable. Sometimes it returns an empty String, though it might return operator codes for other API methods.